# RavenDB : Get store identityname from Type

Tags: ravendb

Using RavenDB, I am trying to find a solution to get the identityname (or whatever it is called) for a type.

For example, let's take that type:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

When I save an instance of it in RavenDB, it generates the following id:

> **product**/1

Is there a function in RavenDB DocumentStore that returns "**product**" when passing in parameter "**typeof(Product)**"? I'm looking for a generic solution that does not require a custom configuration mapping file.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RavenDB 3.0 (3785) you can do the following:

```
var typeTagName = documentStore.Conventions.GetTypeTagName(typeof (Lab));
```

This will use the conventions for your type, and if you have no special conventions registered it will pluralize your type. In this case the results will be: `Labs`

Hope this helps!